# “Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)” -need help re: range

Tags: excel, vba

`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`

I was hoping to ‘borrow’ this bit of code but was unsure what to place in for the range values. Why I wish to use it is for a data page for a workbook full of vlookups.

On this page A through M is filled with data and occasionally is updated, by N through AB has formulas adding two of the data cells or merging information in them. RangeSource and Range Destination seem to be where I might need to adjust-HELP?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: We need more info as to what is changing in your file and how you wish to use this information. The `Worksheet_Change` event is used to measure when a specific cell - or cells - change

Comment: Can you please specify what you want to do and where you're stuck?

Answer (score -1):

I think you are asking how to define the range of cells that should trigger this macro when changed? If so, use this:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:M")) Is Nothing Then
    'Your Code Here
End If
```

That checks to see if the changed cell (Target) is in the defined range (Column A to Column M) and runs your code if it is.

Comment: Will this work if I do not know where the range is going to end (someone else will take over the reporting sheet and does a cut&paste into the A-M cells with the data growing every time.)

Comment: This will work for any cell in the entirety of columns A-M; no matter how many rows. Please provide a bit more information if this doesn't answer your question.